# Can I convert a MS Word document to a Google Document format using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I know how to convert a Microsoft Word document to Google Documents format manually (right click, open with Google Drive). But is there any way to do this using Google Apps Script? I have looked through the help and can't find any methods for files that lets you change the file type, or save in a different format. This seems such an obvious service that I suspect I am missing something.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, that's not possible, even though the request is pending for some time now. If you follow the below mentioned issue (star it; upper left corner), then you will be notified about any change.

### Issue Tracker

- https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585

### Note

The higher the number of votes (star), the higher the chance of it being implemented by the Google Apps Developers team.

Comment: The above link returns "access denied"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues and found a work around. I can't remember where I got it so apologies for not crediting the source.
With this method I created a separate drive folder where the Word document is uploaded to and then a new Google Doc is created alongside it and the text pasted into that. I also had to create a new project in the Google Developers Console in order to get a developer key.

The below code is for a .docx file. For older .doc files change the content type to "application/msword"

```
//Function to convert a Microsoft Word file to a Google Document.
function ConvertWordDoc(file) {
  authorize();
  var key = "YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY"; // <-- developer key

  var metadata = { title: file.getName(),
                   parents: [{
                   "kind": "drive#fileLink",
                   "id": DocsList.getFolder("Folder Name").getId()
                   }]
                 }
  var params = {method:"post",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always",
                contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                contentLength: file.getAs("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document").getBytes().length,
                payload: file.getAs("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document").getBytes()
  };
  var folderName = DocsList.getFolder("Folder Name");
  var uploadRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=media&convert=true&key="+key, params);
  var uploadResponse = Utilities.jsonParse(uploadRequest.getContentText());
  var params = {method:"put",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always",
                contentType: "application/json",
                payload: Utilities.jsonStringify(metadata)
               };
  var metaRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+uploadResponse.id+"?key="+key, params);
  return DocsList.getFileById(uploadResponse.id);
}

function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("drive");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, which I have only just noticed, since gmail concealed the notification in a heap of worthless promotional material.

Comment: A deleted non-answer says: _"docslist is now deprecated, could you update this script to one using driveapp?"_