# How to automatically convert all Microsoft Office file attachments in Gmail to Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script, google-docs

My Gmail has thousands of emails. Each email will have several attachments as Microsoft Office files (**.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx**).

Currently, I want to automatically convert all Microsoft Office file attachments in all my old as well as future emails to Google Document formats and save the converted Google Document file to a separate folder in Google Drive. Then delete the Microsoft Office attachment in the email to reduce storage.

I want to have:

- .doc, .docx convert to Google Docs .xls, .xlsx convert to Google Sheets
- .ppt, .pptx convert to Google Slides.

Is there any way to make the conversion as described above?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of  your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: The big challenge here, I presume, is to **convert .docx to Google doc using apps script**. Here is this sub-problem discussed: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56937/can-i-convert-a-ms-word-document-to-a-google-document-format-using-gas